# As CRTs become less common, how should the concept be introduced to new physicists?

Tags: electromagnetism, education

As [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)s become less common, how should the concept be introduced to new physicists? I've noticed that a lot of introductory material for magnetic fields and moving charges uses the "[tube TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)" as an example of an electron beam in a constant magnetic field, however, this technology is quickly becoming (has become) outdated. I was considering what other examples may be relevant in a pedagogical sense to give a physical example of moving charges in a magnetic field which is easily visualized and present in every day life.

How should teaching the basics of magnetic fields evolve now that the primary technological example used in many texts is no longer as relevant?

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: "What is the single best example?" "How would you replace the CRT in education?" I see your point but I think its a valid line of inquiry

Comment: *"How should teaching the basics of magnetic fields evolve now that the primary technological example used in many texts is no longer as relevant?"* This asks for *opinions*, which is explicitly against Stack Exchange policy. Can you rework this post to ask a specific objective question?

Comment: @DanielSank I think that is only true if you consider teaching to be an opinion-based endeavour. I'm open to suggestions on how better to phrase or convey this, the objective question is how to replace outdated teaching methods/examples

Comment: I don't know what "opinion-based endeavor" means, but I definitely do not think there are objectively "best" practicing in teaching. Effective teaching style depends enormously on the students and lots of other factors numbering so many that I don't think this question is a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. I *do* think this is an *important* topic. Why not come discuss it in chat?

Comment: @DanielSank sounds good. And thinking about it in terms of what I would use as an objective qualification to mark a correct answer I think you have a point.

Comment: Yeah, that's a great way to think about it. If a post doesn't admit a clearly correct answer which obviously should be accepted, then it's not really the right kind of question for Stack Exchange. That's what the chat rooms are for!

Answer (score 1):

This actually came up the other day - I think electron microscopy might be a good example. Students might not have actually interacted with an electron microscope like they would a CRT, but I think it's at least explainable, and somewhat likely that they have at least heard of it. Also, you'd get to say "nano" a lot.

Edit: Are you looking for something specifically with an electron beam? If not, then there's all sorts of possibilities like generators, motors, transformers, etc.

Comment: Most everyday generators, motors and transformers do not house and process electron beams outside wires. What do you have in mind there?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked if they were looking for something specifically with an electron beam. All I know about the lesson is that it has to do with moving charges in magnetic fields, and all these involve magnetic fields.